# Is there a way to enable the MatPaginator next/prev buttons for server side pagination?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was wondering if there was anyway to enable the previous and next button and have them throw events in a mat-paginator.

I have a table that is going to do everything on the backend. I fetch the rows that I need on load and when a user changes the items per page. However, if I have a page set up for 10, query 10, and show 10, the next button is disabled (as would the prev be if I queried a page higher than 1).

Is there a way to make it so that these buttons are not disabled and fire an event so I can call the api for the next set of 10,20,etc?

I've tried getting double the amount of the items per page. This is fine for just changing the items per page, but if a user clicks next, next, next, then prev, prev, and then next, it'll continue loading so I'm not sure how to provide it a cushion

I've tried hacking the hasNextPage() method, trying to set it to true though this is not a good solution since I don't want to fake the return value of the method.

template

```
<mat-paginator
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
  [pageSize]="10"
  (page)="onPaginate($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

component

```
// ViewChild can't catch elem inside an *ngIf in ngAfterViewInit so we set the paginator here
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
  this.paginator = mp
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
  // this.paginator.disabled = false
}

// On Init
this.defects$.subscribe((defects: Defect[]) => {
  if(defects) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(defects)
    this.defects = defects
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
    // this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'asdfasdfasdf'
  }
})

public onPaginate(event): void {

  // this is me trying to get next page not to load unless it's hit the length it's already loaded
  // if(event.previousPageIndex < event.pageIndex) this.numberOfNextPages++
  // else if (event.previousPageIndex > event.pageIndex) this.numberOfPrevPages++


  if(event.previousPageIndex < event.pageIndex && this.numberOfNextPages - this.numberOfPrevPages <= 0) {
    this.pageQuery = `&page=${event.pageIndex}&perPage=${event.length + event.pageSize}`
    this.store.dispatch(new GetDefectListWithQuery(this.companyId, this.sortQuery, this.pageQuery))
  } else if(event.previousPageIndex > event.pageIndex) {
    console.log('hey')
  } else {
    this.pageQuery = `&page=${event.pageIndex + 1}&perPage=${event.pageSize * 2}`  // '&page=1&perPage=10'
    this.store.dispatch(new GetDefectListWithQuery(this.companyId, this.sortQuery, this.pageQuery))
  }
}
```

Ideally, I would want the next and prev buttons enabled (unless they're at the last and first page, respectively) and only query for the pageSize the user has selected in the items per page selection.

However, if that isn't possible, how can I get my paginate logic to only query if it's hit the length that's already been loaded and not keep loading every time someone clicks next?

Comment: Did you find any proper solution for server-side pagination ?